# Get value from window.digitalData.user

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I am trying to get the sku from the following code and if it's exactly that sku do something. The code is:

```js
try {
  window.digitalData.cart = {
    "cartID": "123456789",
    "price": {
      "basePrice": 199,
      "taxRate": 0.2152
    },
    "items": [{
      "productInfo": {
        "productID": "987654321",
        "sku": "AB-123",
        "productName": "Awesome Product"
      }
    }]
  };
  window.digitalData.pluginVersion = "0.3.13";
  window.digitalData.generatedDate = 27387694279472;
} catch (e) {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I need to achieve that using jQuery if possible. I already have the part written what I want to do but never worked with `window.digitalData` before. Also I have the problem that it needs to be exactly this sku and not AB-1234.

So far I used code like this (so you can see I was not lazy):

```
jQuery('li.sku').filter(function () {
    return jQuery(this).text() == 'SKU: AB-123';
}).closest("li.item").addClass("highlighted-product");;
```

So any code or suggestion on how to do it is a help for me :)

Comment: `window.digitalData.cart.items[0].productInfo.sku`

Comment: thats it. thanks a lot my friend from the internet.

Comment: @chris-g is there also a possibility to ignore the [0] so that it could be any number and he doesn't care about it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay have it thanks to [Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g):

```
var absku = 'AB-123';
var abskutwo = window.digitalData.cart.items[0].productInfo.sku;

 if (absku == abskutwo) {
    alert('It works');
 }
```